# Why inheritance is usually used instead of composition when implementing the observer pattern?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, observer-pattern, composition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Observer
{
public:

    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class Subject
{
    std::set<Observer*> observers;

public:

    void addObserver(Observer* observer)
    {
        observers.insert(observer);
    }

    void deleteObserver(Observer* observer)
    {
        observers.erase(observer);
    }

    void notifyObservers()
    {
        for (auto observer : observers)
            observer->update();
    }
};

class HaveValue1 { public: virtual int getValue1() const = 0; };
class HaveValue2 { public: virtual int getValue2() const = 0; };

class ObservingForValue1 : public Observer
{
    HaveValue1* subject;

public:

    ObservingForValue1(HaveValue1* subject) : subject(subject) {}

    virtual void update()
    {
        std::cout << "New value of Value1: " << subject->getValue1() << '\n';
    }
};

class ObservingForValue2 : public Observer
{
    HaveValue2* subject;

public:

    ObservingForValue2(HaveValue2* subject) : subject(subject) {}

    virtual void update()
    {
        std::cout << "New value of Value2: " << subject->getValue2() << '\n';
    }
};

class UsingInheritance : public HaveValue1, public HaveValue2, public Subject
{
    int value1;
    int value2;

public:

    UsingInheritance(int value1, int value2) : value1(value1), value2(value2) {}

    void setValue1(int value) { value1 = value; notifyObservers(); }
    void setValue2(int value) { value2 = value; notifyObservers(); }

    virtual int getValue1() const override { return value1; }
    virtual int getValue2() const override { return value2; }
};

class UsingComposition : public HaveValue1, public HaveValue2
{
    int value1;
    int value2;

    Subject observersForValue1;
    Subject observersForValue2;

public:

    UsingComposition(int value1, int value2) : value1(value1), value2(value2) {}

    void observeValue1(Observer* observer) { observersForValue1.addObserver(observer); }
    void observeValue2(Observer* observer) { observersForValue2.addObserver(observer); }

    void unobserveValue1(Observer* observer) { observersForValue1.deleteObserver(observer); }
    void unobserveValue2(Observer* observer) { observersForValue2.deleteObserver(observer); }

    void setValue1(int value)
    { value1 = value; observersForValue1.notifyObservers(); }

    void setValue2(int value)
    { value2 = value; observersForValue2.notifyObservers(); }

    virtual int getValue1() const override { return value1; }
    virtual int getValue2() const override { return value2; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "With Inheritance:\n";

    UsingInheritance inheritance{ 1, 2 };

    ObservingForValue1 io1{ &inheritance };
    ObservingForValue2 io2{ &inheritance };

    inheritance.addObserver(&io1);
    inheritance.addObserver(&io2);

    inheritance.setValue1(11);
    inheritance.setValue2(22);

    std::cout << "\nWith Composition:\n";

    UsingComposition composition{ 1, 2 };

    ObservingForValue1 co1{ &composition };
    ObservingForValue2 co2{ &composition };

    composition.observeValue1(&co1);
    composition.observeValue2(&co2);

    composition.setValue1(11);
    composition.setValue2(22);
}
```

Output:

```
With Inheritance:
New value of Value2: 2
New value of Value1: 11
New value of Value2: 22
New value of Value1: 11

With Composition:
New value of Value1: 11
New value of Value2: 22
```

I've learned the `observer` pattern from many sources, yet none of them mentioned implementing it with composition. I think using composition is more powerful than inheritance for couple of reasons:

1 - A class can have lots of observers and each one observing for a different thing. If I wanted to achieve the same behavior (having different observers observing `n` different things), I'll have to change the base class so that it supports `n` types of observers and later on, if I wanted it to support `n + 1` observers, I'll have to change it again or inherit from another class. Whereas when using composition, I can just add another `Subject` and that's it.

2 - With inheritance if I wanted to notify the observers, I'll notify all the subscribed ones, even if each one of them is looking for a different thing. Whereas when using composition, I can just notify the desired ones.

3 - Some languages like `java` doesn't allow multiple inheritance, if I inherit from an abstract class that implements some logic of `Subject`, I won't be able to inherit from another class. Whereas using composition, there is a free spot for some class to inherit from.

4 - Composition is prefered over inheritance anyways. If some behavior is achievable using both inheritance and composition, Why the inheritance approach is more popular?

In the code above, I have an `Observer` and a `Subject`. There are 2 types of `Subject`, one using inheritance called `UsingInheritance`, and the other uses composition, called `UsingComposition`. Each one of them has 2 values, `value1` and `value2`. There are 2 observers, `ObservingForValue1` which is only interested in `value1` and `ObservingForValue2` which is only interested in `value2`. Notice that when using `UsingInheritance`, all the subscribed observers get notified even if the value they're interested in didn't change, whereas when using `UsingComposition`, only the desired ones get updated.

Comment: Why did you delete on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/409320/why-inheritance-is-usually-used-instead-of-composition-when-implementing-the-obs)? It seems to be a good fit there…

Comment: @amon Someone wrote a comment asking me to not to corss-post to avoid  fragmented answers splattered over the network.